# Odoo Warning "Perhaps a module was partially removed or renamed"

Tags: odoo-9

When I run odoo server, I got this warning message below.

WARNING dietfacts2 openerp.modules.loading: Model product.nutrientitem is declared but cannot be loaded! (Perhaps a module was partially removed or renamed)

I know that it shows this warning message because I created the model name but then I changed it afterward. The model was saved to postgres DB. I tried to delete the table in DB but unsuccessful.

dietfacts2=# delete from ir_model where model = 'product.nutrientitem';
ERROR:  null value in column "model" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1011, 2017-02-20 04:15:05.207869, 2017-02-20 04:15:05.207869, 285, null, f, false, product_nutrientitem_write_uid_fkey, null, null, null, null).
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "UPDATE ONLY "public"."ir_model_constraint" SET "model" = NULL WHERE $1 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "model""

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Likely you have data in other tables that needs to be cleared first. Try ir_model_data

```
DELETE FROM ir_model_data WHERE model = 'your.model';
```

Then you should be able to delete your table. If you have constraints related to your table you may need to identify these and remove them as well.

Comment: Glad everything is working out for you. If my post helped please mark as correct. Have a good day.

Comment: Perfect! work as charm. I just deleted all the entry from the ir_model_data table and then delete the model from the ir_model. Thank you...

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help.

Answer (score 5):

You have stale model data in your db. Usually is due to a model that has been removed/renamed or a module not uninstalled properly.

A useful module to handle these situations:

https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/11.0/database_cleanup

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/database_cleanup/

It allows you to purge stale data for models, actions, etc, whatever "orphan" record is still in your db. You'll find a control panel for database cleanup under technical section.

Comment: wow, that's great. I tried to install manually this module and it can see thoroughly deep obsolete data entries, column, tables, etc. Thank you!