# Model "model_name" is declared but cannot be loaded when adding new fields to module

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I'm total newbie and I'm currently fighting with problem during the process while developing new model.

I started with just a basic model definition (see below):

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class EmployeeGoals(models.Model):
    _name = 'employee.goals'
    _description = 'Employee Goals'

    name = fields.Char(string="Description")
    goal_type  = fields.Selection([('p','Professional'),('i','Individual')], string = 'Goal type')
```

At that point everything was fine I saw default attributes and those new ones as well (name and goal_type)

When I tried to add new attribute there ( goal_percent = fields.Interger(string="Percentage") ) and checked my model in Odoo itself (Under Databases) nothing was displayed there (empty) and in the log I saw:

```
2019-04-24 18:35:51,668 4373 INFO odoo odoo.modules.registry: module employee_goals: creating or updating database tables
2019-04-24 18:35:51,702 4373 INFO odoo odoo.modules.loading: loading employee_goals/views/views.xml
2019-04-24 18:35:51,704 4373 INFO odoo odoo.modules.loading: loading employee_goals/views/templates.xml
2019-04-24 18:35:51,705 4373 INFO odoo odoo.modules.loading: Module employee_goals: loading demo
2019-04-24 18:35:51,705 4373 INFO odoo odoo.modules.loading: loading employee_goals/demo/demo.xml
2019-04-24 18:35:51,756 4373 INFO odoo odoo.modules.loading: 31 modules loaded in 0.12s, 0 queries
2019-04-24 18:35:51,886 4373 WARNING odoo odoo.modules.loading: Model employee.goals is declared but cannot be loaded! (Perhaps a module was partially removed or renamed)
```

If I'm removing that last attribute "goal_percent" it starts to work again and my attributes is displayed in odoo as well. so I assume it could be something wrong with data in postgres itself? But the thing is that it is just vase of my model and nothing was been inserted in the database itself. Just defined the model at the moment.

Seems that this problem popped up as well when I tried to change the name of the field.

Comment: After inserting a new attribute you need to upgrade the module. Have you upgraded?

Comment: Yep, tried it multiple times. It just seems that it doesn't like something in DB and as I said, before adding something I saw my fields in Database models view for that specific module, but after adding new ones and upgrading it it appears empty.

Comment: I think it's the same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42357362/odoo-warning-perhaps-a-module-was-partially-removed-or-renamed

Answer (score 1):

Check your spelling

new_field = fields.Integer(string="", required=False, )

You have 
( goal_percent = fields.Interger(string="Percentage")

You misspelled Integer. You spelt as Interger, but should be Integer

eg

goal_percent = fields.Integer(string="Percentage")

That should work. If it doesn't, check with a new field Char and see if it's not the integer that's having a problem (shouldn't be but good to test). eg fields.Char